# How to place "anything" in puppet class?

Tags: puppet

There will be different mount directories on various hosts.What operator and what is best way to add "anything" in code.I have tried using "*" ,it did not work.

```
class database::settings {
    mount { '/mydata/<anything>/data':
        options  => 'commit=100000000',
        remounts => false,
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, wildcards like that aren't a thing in mount resources (or many other Puppet resources). Is there a parameter (hostname?) that is available to build the exact mount point?

Comment: Hostnames are not in order.Those are named random.

Comment: Could you clarify what `<anything>` is? Well, it’s a filename, but beside that. Could you provide some example values and what they represent?